# SplashScreen Activity onClick to open MainActivity and replace fragment in that Activity's fragment container

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hi really struggling with this one, hence my first post after a day of searching for a solution with no luck.

I have a splash screen which has an ImageView with an onClickListener which when clicked opens up my MainActivity just fine:

#### SplashActivity.java

```
      bookMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
```

However what I'm trying to achieve is, when the button is clicked, it opens my MainActivity, but replace's the fragment_container in the MainActivity I have with another fragment (this is how my bottombar Navigation works).

This is the code in the MainActivity that handles the replacing of fragments when navigation buttons are clicked and essentially I want the Splash Screen's click to open up the "BookFragment" rather than go straight to the "RoomsFragment":

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //STANDARD ON CREATE OPEN TO LOAD INITIAL LAYOUT
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


//THIS CREATES A BLANK CONTAINER FOR EACH FRAGMENT YOU CREATE TO GO IN
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        RoomsFragment firstFragment = new RoomsFragment();
        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();


//THIS CREATES THE NAV BAR AND TELLS WHAT FRAGMENT TO PUT IN THE CONTAINER WHEN A TAB IS SELECTED
        BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                //TAB1 - THE DEFAULT TAB
                if (tabId == R.id.tab_rooms) {

                    RoomsFragment newFragment = new RoomsFragment();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();

                    //TAB2
                } else if (tabId == R.id.tab_shisha) {

                    // THIS BIT BELOW IS WHAT CHANGES THE FRAGMENT IN THE CONTAINER
                    ShishaFragment newFragment = new ShishaFragment();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();

                    //TAB3
                } else if (tabId == R.id.tab_cocktails) {

                    // THIS BIT BELOW IS WHAT CHANGES THE FRAGMENT IN THE CONTAINER
                    CocktailsFragment newFragment = new CocktailsFragment();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();

                    //TAB4
                } else if (tabId == R.id.tab_food) {

                    // THIS BIT BELOW IS WHAT CHANGES THE FRAGMENT IN THE CONTAINER
                    FoodFragment newFragment = new FoodFragment();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();

                    //TAB5
                } else if (tabId == R.id.tab_book) {

                    // THIS BIT BELOW IS WHAT CHANGES THE FRAGMENT IN THE CONTAINER
                    BookFragment newFragment = new BookFragment();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }


            }


        });
```

#### Corrected working SplashActivity.java:

In the onCreate method:

```
//ONCLICK LISTENER FOR THE ENTER BUTTON AND BOOK BUTTON ON SPLASH PAGE


    Button enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter_button);
    enterButton.setOnClickListener(SplashActivity.this);

    Button bookButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.book_button);
    bookButton.setOnClickListener(SplashActivity.this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.enter_button:

            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.book_button:

            intent.putExtra("source","onClick");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

#### Corrected working MainActivity.java

In the onCreate method (enter the position of the tab of the bottomBar relevant to you):

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String source = intent.getStringExtra("source");
        if (source != null && source.equals("onClick")) {
            bottomBar.selectTabAtPosition(4);
        }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you use this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```

it's will show the `firstFragment` default

you can try this:

In Spalsh Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

add some params for intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("source","onClick");   //add like this line
startActivity(intent);
```

In Main Activity

````
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ```your code

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String source = intent.getStringExtra("source");
    if (source.equals("onClick")) {
        bottomBar.onTabSelected(R.id.tab_book);
    }
}
````

when Main Activity incept the params `source`,and the `source` value is your set, it's will run the code in `if`

Comment: Hi there, this seems like exactly the sort of thing I need to do, I'm just struggling to implement it. I've tried to put the code that needs to go into the MainActivity in there but it doesn't seem to want to change the fragment to the "Book tab". Would you mind showing me exactly where it needs to go ? Also worth noting that there is two buttons on my splash page one is "Enter" and one is "Book". The "Enter" tab goes straight to the MainActivity so loads the default tab which is "Rooms" but the Book button is where I am struggling to get it to go to the Book fragment.

Comment: Ok so I've finally got it! The code was perfect but there is no "onTabSelected" class (?) in the bottomBar library so I had to use "selectTabAtPosition" in it's place and select the position of the tab. The only issue with this now is, is when I click on the "Enter" button now, I get a : "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference" error.

When I take out the Intent code out of the MainActivity the enter button works, so not sure what exactly I need to amend :S ?

Comment: I've added the updated the main post here to show my updated "SplashActivity" with both of the listeners. Think this may be the problem, almost there :)

Comment: So I've updated the onClickListener to work how it is meant to now, however I still receive the same issue when I click the "Enter" button. The intent on the "Book" button works fine but just the main "Enter" button crashes the app with a NullPointerException. I've put the onClickListener change in the main post.

Comment: So as you can see I have been at this all day! Managed to get to the bottom of this though so I've added the code that needed to change to make this work in the end, hopefully it will help someone. I've accepted this answer as it was ultimately what helped me to move forward with this, many thanks!!!

Comment: sorry，I went to sleep and dont login this so I dont see ur comment, the `onTabSelected` is ur bottomBar's method, I dont know what for ur code, it's mean ur bottomBar's Book tab click, such like `R.id.tab_book`'s onClickListener, hope to help u.